# Scroll horizontal en menú de navegacion

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

En la web indicada al final de la pregunta, en la vista para dispositivos móviles, se puede observar que los últimos elementos del menú no se ven (como "ojotas" por ejemplo). Si yo deslizo con el dedo, se mueve el sitio completo.

Yo quisiera dejar el sitio estático (quitarle el overflow x) pero permitir deslizar el menu de izquierda a derecha para poder verlo por completo, sin importar cuantos elementos tenga.

> No se si la pregunta es clara. Yo quisiera que el menu de navegacion se comporte exactamente igual que un slider, permitiendo deslizarme horizontalmente sin afectar al resto del sitio

https://flipashowroom.com.ar/

Answer (score 0):

agrega esta linea a tu codigo html dentro de la etiqueta HEAD y asi la pagina va a adaptarse a las medidas de la pantalla con la que se abra

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```